# The getter 'path' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting this error when I pickn no video how can I manage that error ?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The getter 'path' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: path

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib/main.dart:49
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _OnlymeinebeitraegeState.pickvideo.<anonymous closure> (package:wichtigdenyady/seitenleiste/onlymeinebeitr%C3%A4ge.dart:359:39)
#2      MaterialPageRoute.buildContent
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:54
#3      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:107
#4      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:840
...
═════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is the code

```
 pickvideo(ImageSource src) async {
    final video = await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: src);
    NavigationService.instance.navigateToRoute(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return CreateVideo(File(video.path), video.path, src);
      }),
    );
  }

  void showPickOptionsDialog(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                content:
                    Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Pick from Gallery"),
                onTap: () {
                  pickvideo(ImageSource.gallery);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Take a Video"),
                onTap: () {
                  pickvideo(ImageSource.camera);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ])));
  }
```

The error throws in the pickvideo method hope anyone can help if you need more information please a comment and tell me which informations. Also if you need more code please also leave a comment and tell me which part you need

Comment: The error indicates that the video variable is null. Try make some debug to see what is being returned by the ImagePicker().getVideo.

Comment: it is null when I just pick no video when I pick one it works but when not then im getting this error thats my question how to solve that if I pick no video sorry for bad explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a check after picking:

```
final video = await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: src);
if(video != null) {
  NavigationService.instance.navigateToRoute(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return CreateVideo(File(video.path), video.path, src);
    }),
  );
}else{
  //do something else, like show user a message
}
```